# Why do we need IIS Express?

Tags: windows-7, iis-express

Today I notice my team having to apply a registry patch to switch to `IIS Express x64` so that ImageMagikc would work.

The patch is executed via a .bat file as below.

My question is why do we need to use IIS Express while IIS is already available in Windows 7/8?

p.s.

How would we find the similar name for IIS Express for Apache web server?

```
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\WebProjects /v Use64BitIISExpress /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

Answer (score 1):

IIS Express runs as a normal program under your own user account and so no special privileges are required to debug when using it. IIS runs as a service under a separate account and admin (or admin-like) permissions are required to debug with it.

As part of the "encourage everyone not to run everything as admin 100% of the time" effort, it makes sense to have the former available.

Comment: I don't get it. How would we find the similar name for IIS Express for Apache web server?